# Need Logic for Running Excel by Java code using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, selenium, automation, apache-poi

**Please help me in this  where i wanted a scenario that will return me all the test Methods (column B) for the corresponding class name ,here i am trying to create a function tHAT WILL RETURN ME method list for a perticular class  //we may use some collection framework (as am new to java dont know how exactly to do this) please see attached image **

```html
@Test
 public void excel() throws Exception{

  ExcelUtils.setExcelFile("E:\\EclipseTests\\DemoTests\\src\\main\\java\\testdata\\testdata.xls", "Sheet1");
  int ic=ExcelUtils.getRowUsed();

  int row=utility.ExcelUtils.getRowContains("Class1", 0);
  System.out.println("row num  "+row);
  
  List<String>value=method("Class1",ic);//need to  get all the values of column B in the excel when 
  //i put class name/column 0 value in this function byietrating using loop
  } 
public static List<String>method(String classz ,int ic) throws Exception{
  for(int i=1;i<ic;i++){ 
   
   List<String>sMethod=new ArrayList<String>();
   String sClassName=ExcelUtils.getCellData(i, 0);
   String sClassName1=ExcelUtils.getCellData(i-1, 0);
   if(sClassName1.equals(sClassName)  ){
    int row=utility.ExcelUtils.getRowContains(sClassName, 0);
    //need to write some logic which will return me a list which will contains 
     //[Test1 ,Test2 ,Test3 ,Test4 ,Test5] for class1 
    sMethod.add("value from B column");// i.e Test1
    sMethod.add("value from B column");// i.e Test2
    sMethod.add("value from B column");// i.e Test3
    sMethod.add("value from B column");// i.e Test4
    sMethod.add("value from B column");// i.e Test5
   }

  }
  
  return sMethod;
  }
}

//similarly for class2 it should return [Test6,Test7,Test8,Test9,Test10]
//similarly for class3 it should return [Test6,Test11,Test12,Test13,Test14]
```

[image: Excel sheet pic]

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); rowIndex++) {
  row = sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
  if (row != null) {
    String cellValue = null;
    for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells(); colIndex++) {
      if (colIndex == 1) { //as index of column B will be 1
        cell = row.getCell(colIndex);
        if (cell != null) {
          // Found column and there is value in the cell.
          cellValue = cell.getStringCellValue();
          break;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

add this cellvalue variable in list or array

Comment: Thanks Poojan for your effort.it only gave me column B values ,What i wanted was ,it should return me only column B values for respective Column a value

Answer (score 0):

```
@SuppressWarnings("null")
public static List<String>methods(String clasName){

    List<String>method=new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int rowIndex = 1; rowIndex <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); rowIndex++) {
        row = sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
        if (row != null) {  
            HSSFCell cell=sheet.getRow(rowIndex).getCell(0);
            if(cell.getStringCellValue().equalsIgnoreCase(clasName)){

                String value=sheet.getRow(rowIndex).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
                System.out.println( value);
                method.add(value);
            }
        }
    }

    return method;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    FileInputStream ExcelFile = new FileInputStream("E:\\EclipseTests\\DemoTests\\src\\main\\java\\testdata\\testdata.xls");
    wb=new HSSFWorkbook(ExcelFile);
    sheet=wb.getSheet("Sheet1");

    System.out.println("value is "+methods("Class3"));
    System.out.println("value is "+methods("Class1"));
    System.out.println("value is "+methods("Class4"));
```

This is what i was looking for..Thanks everyone